# How to overwrite a style in css which is coming from multiple media queries.?

Tags: html, css

I am using multiple media queries for different iPhones and got stuck when a class has some style but doesn't override in other media query.

For some classes I used `!important` to overwrite the CSS Rule but if the class has already `!important` used then the CSS rule doesn't override.

I am confused in this state whether I should use different class names in the same element to define CSS rules in different media queries.

I am giving the link of google drive for the problem statement - https://drive.google.com/open?id=12KC_qtBwuxLGUW8KZAb-YoqUUBzxP3Q7

Comment: You can add images directly in SO

Comment: Could you add the full CSS code corresponding to your problem ?

Comment: Never use important unless you need to override an inline style you have no control over - if you do, then you find yourself in this situation, instead learn about css specifics and use that properly

Comment: Also, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code in the question (not just an external link to a google drive) - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

You can hierarchal css structure for the same.

For example as per the drive link::

```
.xl-block .sidemenu-link {
    font-size: 24px !important;
}
```